# How to position controls relative to one central control?

Tags: wpf

[image]
This is what the final windows should look like. The blue box should represent an user control (for multiple use) which is added to the main window. The red circle represents the central control and the other blue circles are controls which should be positioned relative to the red one (i.e. the yellow center point).

I tried using a grid but faced the problem that I cannot overlap the cells such that the blue circle overlaps with the red one. I think it is possible to solve this somehow with a canvas and absolute positioning but then scaling might be the problem.

Do you know a better way of achieving this?

Comment: When you say "other blue circles are controls which should be positioned relative to the red one" you mean just left, top, right, bottom OR across the circumference of red circle?

Comment: What I mean is that I want to position a control relative to the (yellow) center point of the red circle. E.g assume the radius of the red circle is 50 and I want to position a blue circle on the circumference I add (or substract) 25 to the xPos of the red circle. This way I want to be able to place the control on any spot I want.

Comment: Of course you can "overlap the cells". Use Grid.RowSpan and Grid.ColumnSpan on the items in the grid. But it might be better to calculate the locations on SizeChanged.

Answer (score 1):

To place a Usercontrol on the circumference of a circle, I'd suggest you to use Canvas.

```
<Canvas x:Name="canvas">
   <Ellipse  Canvas.Left="100" Canvas.Top="100" Width="50" Height="50" Stroke="Red"  />
<\Canvas>
```

Now assuming name of your UserControl is `BlueControl` -

```
var blueControl = new BlueControl();
PlaceAt(0.0, blueControl); // This will place the blueControl at 0 degree radian from horizontal axis.
```

And the helper function -

```
private void PlaceAt(double radian, FrameworkElement element)
{
    double cx = 100 + 50.0 / 2; // Left start position of red circle + radius of it.
    double cy = 100 + 50.0 / 2; // Top start position of red circle + radius of it.
    double x = cx + r * Math.Cos(radian) + element.Width / 2.0;
    double y = cy - r * Math.Sin(radian) + element.Height / 2.0;
    Canvas.SetLeft(element, x);
    Canvas.SetTop(element, y);
    canvas.Children.Add(element);
}
```

This code should get you started in what you want.